# no application switcher in fullscreen?

Tags: fullscreen

Hi is it a bug or was it actually designed so ?
when an application is in fullscreen and i hit 'alt-tab' the applications that would normaly show are hidden.
any idea on how to fix this ? if possible at all.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open System Settings from the launchbar and click 'Keyboard' then 'Shortcuts' then 'Windows'

You can assign alt+tab there as a windows switcher.

Comment: alt-tab is working except when in fullscreen, it continues to work but it is hidden, it doesn't show the windows switcher